# Function that takes two vectors and returns a matrix z=f(x,y) in R

Tags: r, function, matrix

I am trying to define a scalar function of `a` and `b`, where `a` and `b` are vectors so I can make a surface plot of `z=f(X,y)` using `persp(a,b,z)`.

The problem is, the return value of my function is a vector of the same length as my vector `a`, when I expected a matrix.

the function in question is:

```
logver <- function(a, b, PARAM) {
  l <- (1 / (1 + exp(-a - b * PARAM)))
  return(l)
}
```

Anyone knows what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all possible combinations of `a` and `b`, use `outer`.

```
logver <- function(a, b, PARAM)
{
    o <- outer(a, b*PARAM, `+`)
    1/(1 + exp(-o))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
logover <- function(a, b, PARAM){
    L <- (1 / (1 + exp(-a-b*PARAM)))
    return(L)
}
```

Type `return(L)` in a new line with an indentation. You won't get any error.

What are the values you are trying to pass for a, b and PARAM ??

Comment: the return(l) part is in another line with indentation, for some reason it keeps getting ignored when I copy and paste it in here. PARAM is a regular number, say 2. a and b were generated using seq(-10,10,by=0.01)

Comment: Problem is, I expected to get a value for each value of a and b; a matrix, while I am getting a vector (of length 2001).

Comment: When you use seq(-10,10,by=0.01) it returns both the values thus returns 2001 values. You need to decide which value you can skip either on the left side or the side. You can change it to seq(-9.99,10,by=0.01) OR seq(-10,9.99,by=0.01). This will give only 2000 values.

Comment: The problem is not the vectors the function takes as arguments, the problem is that I am getting a vector as the output value, while I want a matrix,

Comment: You can try return(matrix(L, 1000, 2)) to get the matrix form.  Or can you show the sample output which you are expecting.